# retrieve form element to generate next element (google-script)

Tags: google-forms

A bit of a noob so please forgive me.

I am working on a project using Google Sheets and Google Forms.  I would love to use javascript and html but I am required to use google.

I have a google form with a drop down.  I need to read the value of the drop down and pass it to a google script I have written.  The script will populate the values for another question in the same form based on the dropdown value.  I need to retrieve the value before the form is submitted so I can create the second question.

Can this be done all on one page?
If not can I create a second page in the form and read the value when the next button is clicked?

I appreciate any info and feedback you can provide. I have tried looking around on the internet but haven really found solutions that helped me, at least not that i understood.

Thanks

Comment: A Google Form can not be dynamically updated as the user is filling out the Form.  You can not do what you want to with a Google Form.  You will need to use an Apps Script Web App to do what you want.  An Apps Script Web App is basically a web site, but you can not get a domain name.  It's free.  You will need to provide the URL to the users, but you need to do that with a Google Form also.  If you are embedding the Google Form into a website, and you want to embed the Web App into a website, I'm not sure about how to do that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if I can capture the data from a field when the user clicks the next button that I can programmatically generate a question on the next page with an onload() event. I'm just trying to get the form data when the user clicks the next button.

Comment: You can't get the data when the user clicks the "Next" button.  There is no way to do that in a Google Form.